# .strip() method not stripping mystery whitespace characters

Tags: python, string, strip

I am reading some utf-8 encoded data from a file like so:

```
with open (filename, 'rb') as f:
    bytes= f.read(offset, length)
    #bytes is b'hello\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    text = bytes.decode('utf-8')
    #text is 'hello    '
    stripped_text = text.strip()
    #stripped_text is 'hello    '
```

You can recreate this with a simple line like

```
thing = b'hello\x00\x00\x00\x00'.decode('utf8').strip()
print(thing)
#the output is 'hello    '
```

As you can see, the trailing nul characters are not stripped - I assume this has something to do with '\x00' not being recognized by .strip() but everywhere I look seems to think it should be. What gives? How can I remove these characters without having to do something very clunky?

I couldn't find a post which addressed this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NULs are not whitespace, so `strip()` with no arguments will not strip them.  You should instead use `strip('\0')`:

```
>>> 'hello\0\0\0\0'.strip('\0')
'hello'
```

Comment: Thank you - this is working, but what is the '\0' argument? the string that strip() is being called on is 'hello    '. is '\0' interpreted as a nul character? Where in the docs is that?

Comment: @Nate: [The argument to `strip()` is the set of characters to remove.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) `'\0'` is another way to spell `'\x00'`, the NUL character (The first uses an octal escape, the latter a hexadecimal escape; see [the tables here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for more information).

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware you could specify NUL in a string in that way.

Comment: @Nate Curiously, I can't see any documentation for `\<number>` escape sequences in [the relevant section about string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: @Aran-Fey: It's the `\ooo` line near the bottom of the first table.

Comment: @jwodder Interesting! I had no idea `\8` and `\9` weren't escape sequences.